# No instructions for sealed Lego bags

Tags: set-identification, instructions

I have 4 sealed bags of lego with no instructions. Each bag has a QR code which provides a number (one is 6172062) but nothing comes up online.

Please see photo below of bags.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

KR
Mark

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These bags appear to be from ["90 Years of Play" (11021)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=11021-1) set released in 2022. You can download instructions [directly from LEGO](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/11021). Identified by [Technic, Brick 1 x 4 with Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3701&colorID=3&in=A) in Yellow.

[image]